# Vba crashing when run, works correctly in debug

Tags: vba, excel

I have some vba code within a userform which opens a bunch of sheets each with one line of code in, based on conditions from the userform. It should then copy the data into a table in another workbook.
It works correctly when in debug, but when in play it manages about 30 lines then crashes and restarts excel.

Code below...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Cancel_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub Run_Click()

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim file As Variant
Dim wo As String
Dim wb As String
Dim openwb As String
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim oFS As Object
Dim strFilename As String

If ListBox1.Value <> "" Then
    wo = ListBox1.Value

    Workbooks.Add
    wb = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    file = Dir("\\hlepcs01\Runtime_CMM\Gauging\mast_dat\SmartWall\")
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    n = 2
    x = 1

    While (file <> "")
        If InStr(Left(file, 4), wo) > 0 Then
            Workbooks("Smartwall Data Collate.xlsm").Sheets("Datasheet").Range("C" & n).Value = file
            n = n + 1
        End If
    file = Dir
    Wend

    For i = 2 To (n - 2)

        openwb = Workbooks("Smartwall Data Collate.xlsm").Sheets("Datasheet").Range("C" & i).Value

        Workbooks.Open ("\\hlepcs01\Runtime_CMM\Gauging\mast_dat\SmartWall\" & openwb)

        r = 1
        c = 1

        Do Until Cells(r, c).Value = ""
            If Cells(r, c).Value <> "" Then
                c = c + 1
            End If
        Loop

        If c <= 1 Then
            GoTo 1
        End If
        Workbooks(openwb).Activate
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, (c - 2))).Copy
        Workbooks(wb).Activate
        Range("C" & x).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Workbooks(openwb).Activate
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Cells(1, (c - 1)).Copy
        Workbooks(wb).Activate
        Range("B" & x).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Range("A" & x).Value = oFS.GetFile("\\hlepcs01\Runtime_CMM\Gauging\mast_dat\SmartWall\" & openwb).DateCreated

        x = x + 1
1
        Workbooks(openwb).Close

    Next

Workbooks("Smartwall Data Collate.xlsm").Sheets("Datasheet").Range("C2:C" & (n - 2)).ClearContents

If n <= 2 Then
    Workbooks(wb).Close , xlNo
    MsgBox "No Data Found"
End If

Unload Me

Else
    MsgBox "No Works Order Selected"
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer

lastrow = Workbooks("Smartwall Data Collate.xlsm").Sheets("Datasheet").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    With ListBox1
        .AddItem Workbooks("Smartwall Data Collate.xlsm").Sheets("Datasheet").Range("A" & i).Value
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't seem to care about identifying which worksheet you are working with. Just the workbook and range.

Comment: when something works in debug but not when run normally it is most usually a question of not identifying the right worksheet in code. In your case  Cells(r, c) alone actually means Activesheet.Cells(r,c)  - It may not be the sheet you think it is.

Comment: I'll try adding the sheet line but each workbook only has one sheet, so by stating which workbook it already knows what sheet as there is only one.

Comment: The point is unqualified `Cells` calls implicitly work off `ActiveSheet`, and that makes code extremely frail. Qualify all `Cells` and `Range` calls, you'll fix the problem. You shouldn't need to `.Activate` anything.

Comment: All unqualified cells now have a workbook, sheet and range reference... have just tested and is still not working.

Comment: Show us the udpated code :) ..also if possible, identify specifically which line throws the error, and what the error message is.

Comment: Please update the code in your question and also reboot your computer before trying again (recommended after crashes)

Comment: @Ryan2711 why the `1` on a line by itself?  Also, the FSO is used only to get a date, correct? also, this `Workbooks(wb).Close , xlNo` is looking for a file named `xlNo` (which is 2) .  Those are the first things I noticed. It would be a good idea to step through your code line by line with F8 and make sure all the values are what you think they are. If you still have an issue, start taking out code until there is no crash. Then add it back in one line at a time, running each time, until it's obvious which one was causing the problem.

Comment: perhaps the `filedatetime` function would suffice so you don't need to use FSO for one date.

Comment: @ashleedawg that lonely `1` is legal, it's parsed as a line number. It's confusing because normally one doesn't need line numbers at all, and when `GoTo` is used it's preferable to jump to a line *label* instead of a line *number* anyway. The control flow should probably be refactored so as to eliminate that `GoTo 1` conditional jump - I'd start by pulling the body of the loop into its own function/scope =)

Comment: The 1 on the line is a label to allow a conditional jump based on the if statment. Yes the FSO is used to get the date the files being open were created - this date is then entered into a cell.

Comment: Update... computer has been rebooted and ajusted code ran. It is still not working, it will collate 37 lines from the other files before closing down and then reopening as a recovered file. I can't identify a line that is causing the error as it works fine in debug and when in play it doesn't throw any errors - just shuts excel down.